# Are there any good video tutorials for Hibernate ?

Tags: hibernate

I'm new to `Hibernate`, are there any good online video tutorials to guide me ?

Thanks.

Comment: [video-tutorial-on-spring-and-hibernate](http://basics-in-java.blogspot.in/2014/02/video-tutorial-on-spring-and-hibernate.html)

Comment: In case you haven't mastered it already, a course on Hibernate and JPA fundamentals has been released by http://mavenedge.com recently. See if you find that useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For beginners, these are [some video tutorials that are easy to follow](http://youtube.com/user/patrickwashingtondc).

If you want to get the most out of Hibernate, check out [Vlad Mihalcea's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgm4Z7xTH7iQlpZu69rHvkg). He's a Hibernate Developer Advocate, so can be more entitled to teach you how Hibernate works if not the people who actually develop this framework, right?

Answer (score 12):

These [hibernate tutorial videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4AFF701184976B25) are excellent.

There are also training videos on [Maven](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL92E89440B7BFD0F6) & [Spring](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7) on the [Java Brains youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/koushks).

Answer (score 7):

http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/hibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: apologies, this was a question about hibernate not nhibernate, I'll leave my answer up just in case others are coming here for an nhibernate suggestion.

The video series that really jump started my learning and use of NHibernate was [Steven Bohlen's](http://twitter.com/sbohlen) Summer of NHibernate series. It is about 20 hours long and is a great starting point.

I also learned a lot about how to do integration testing with a database (because the video series goes through writing these tests)

http://summerofnhibernate.com/

Comment: There's a difference between hibernate & nhibernate

Comment: ah, you're right.... my mind just sees nhibernate because that is the world i live in. sorry about that.

Comment: From what I've scene the differences between Hibernate and NHibernate are subtle. Some of the differecnes are: Class locations, and property names.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are not videos on hibernate. However, there is an intro guide on the [official website](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/) and there is a well known book on Amazon: [Hibernate In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193239415X).

Comment: -1 because there are videos on Hibernate, as many of the answers have shown.

Answer (score 0):

A google search brings this up:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLOiW9Lw4mo